# Why are environment variables not being set inside of my docker container?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have the following in my docker-compose.yml:

```
  php:
    build:
      args:
        http_proxy:
        https_proxy:
        no_proxy:
      context: ./vm-images/php
    environment:
      http_proxy:
      https_proxy:
      no_proxy:
      CURRENT_ENVIRONMENT: DOCKER
    container_name: php
    ports:
      - "9000:9000"
    depends_on:
      - mysql
    links:
      - mysql:mysql
    logging:
      driver: "json-file"
    volumes:
      - /var/www/:/var/www/
```

My DOCKERFILE has the following:

```
FROM ubuntu:latest

RUN locale-gen en_US.UTF-8 && \
    export LANG=en_US.UTF-8 && \
    export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y --reinstall ca-certificates

RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y --allow-unauthenticated --no-install-recommends \
    software-properties-common python-software-properties

RUN add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php

RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y --allow-unauthenticated --no-install-recommends \
    git-core \
    libjpeg-progs \
    mysql-client \
    optipng \
    php5.6 \
    php5.6-curl \
    php5.6-intl \
    php5.6-fpm \
    php5.6-gd \
    php5.6-mcrypt \
    php5.6-mysqli \
    php5.6-pdo \
    php5.6-xdebug \
    php5.6-xml \
    php5.6-zip

RUN rm -r /var/lib/apt/lists/*
RUN rm -r /var/cache/apt/*

RUN php -r "copy('https://getcomposer.org/installer', 'composer-setup.php');" && \
    php -r "if (hash_file('SHA384', 'composer-setup.php') === 'e115a8dc7871f15d853148a7fbac7da27d6c0030b848d9b3dc09e2a0388afed865e6a3d6b3c0fad45c48e2b5fc1196ae') { echo 'Installer verified'; } else { echo 'Installer corrupt'; unlink('composer-setup.php'); } echo PHP_EOL;" && \
    php composer-setup.php --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer && \
    php -r "unlink('composer-setup.php');"

RUN mkdir -p /run/php && chown www-data:www-data /run/php 

COPY files/etc/php/fpm/php-fpm.conf /etc/php/5.6/fpm/php-fpm.conf
COPY files/etc/php/fpm/pool.d/www.conf /etc/php/5.6/fpm/pool.d/www.conf
COPY files/etc/php/fpm/php.ini /etc/php/5.6/fpm/php.ini
COPY files/etc/php/cli/php.ini /etc/php/5.6/cli/php.ini
COPY files/etc/php/mods-available/xdebug.ini /etc/php/5.6/mods-available/xdebug.ini

RUN phpenmod curl intl gd mcrypt mysqli pdo xdebug xml zip

CMD ["php-fpm5.6", "--nodaemonize", "--fpm-config", "/etc/php/5.6/fpm/php-fpm.conf"]
```

When I run `docker-compose --verbose up -d` I notice that there are no env vars passed in for my php container. I've verified that those env vars are set on my host, and they are passed in for all of my other containers without fail. Anyone have any ideas?

EDIT: Strangely enough, I've also noticed that `/proc/$PID/environ` (where $PID is the PID of the php container [obtained by running `docker inspect --format "{{.State.Pid}}" php`] on the host machine is empty.

Comment: Are you looking for `CURRENT_ENVIRONMENT: DOCKER`? Because the exports in your Dockerfile will only apply to the shell in your first RUN line, and be gone in all following RUN lines.

Comment: I'm looking for all of the environment variables specified in the docker-compose.yml when I `up` my containers. I don't have any EXPORTS lines in my Dockerfile at all. All of that is supposed to be taken care of by docker-compose.yml automatically (there are several environment variables that are supposed to be inherited from the host machine, like http_proxy).

Comment: I wonder why you install all by yourself when there is official image php:5.6-fpm available

Comment: @mike there's a bug with the official php image and xdebug causing a fatal error when you hit a static method while debugging. It's fixed in the image for 7.0, but I need 5.6.

Comment: @BMitch in case I wasn't clear, the env vars are set fine for my `build` process - just not my `run` one. Any ideas?

Comment: Unless it's something simple like a space vs tab in the yml file, I'm out of ideas.

Comment: @BMitch I thought that might be the case, too, so I ran it through a yaml validator, and it checks out.

Comment: You should define your environment variables using `ENV` see the doc https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#/env

Comment: @user2915097 I can't, because they change at runtime - not build time.

Comment: @user2915097 In addition, I'm using the correct format in docker-compose.yml to set those environment variables at runtime, but it's not working.